# Net user in for /f Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use this command:

```
    NET USER %username% /DOMAIN | FIND /I " name "
```

in conjunction with a `for /f` to retrieve the full username and set it as a variable and ultimately output to a file.  I have tried several variations but none are working properly.  I think my problem is in working with the `for /f` command:

```
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=  " %%f in ('net user %username% /domain^|Find 
   /I " name "') do set user=%%f
```

The username will presumably always have a space in it as well.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please edit some example lines being returned by your `net user...` command into your question. Your command returned an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use quotes in the 'file-set' then you need to use back quotes. Try this:

```
   for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%f in (`net user "%username%" /domain ^|Find /I " name "`) do set user=%%f %%g
```

Note that I changed both of the ' to ` and added a space after domain.
See FOR /?

Edited to add * and %%g to get entire name including spaces in first name and last name.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  This is much closer than I was before, but it is still not returning the correct data. I am getting the entire line and not just the user name listed at the end of the line.

Comment: That is correct. You are telling it to display lines that contain the string " name ". If you want just the name you will have to parse the line.

Comment: Took out the "Delims=  " and changed tokens to 3.

Comment: This works somewhat but given that the name is Last name, First name.  It is only storing the last name as the variable, Is there a way to keep the whole name given that it has a space separating the two?

Comment: See my edit to get entire name. You will need to modify if you need to separate last name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help RGuggisberg, you got me 90% of the way.  I was able to figure out the rest myself and clean it up a little.  Here is what I came up with:

```
    for /f "usebackq tokens=3,4" %%f in (`net user "%username%" /domain 
    ^|Find /I " name "`) do (
        set last=%%f
        set last=!last:~0,-1%!
        set first=%%~g
    )
```

It also allowed me to have each part of the name as a variable so I can swap them around, removed the "," from the last name and leading spaces from the first name.  Thanks again for your help!